# Node.js: trouble with asynchronous code + js closures

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, closures

I'm having trouble adapting to Node's single threaded + asynchronous nature, coupled with javascript's function closures.

Suppose I have something like:

```
function foo(bar) {
    someAsyncFunction(function callback(err) {
        // do stuff with 'bar'
    });
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something; but my understanding was that:

- Due to closure, `callback` will have a *reference* to `bar`
- However, if `foo` is called once with `bar` = 20, then again with
  `bar = 42` **before** `callback` is invoked from the first call, then `bar` will be 42 in `callback` resulting from first call of `foo`. In
  other words:

  1. `foo(20)` #1
  2. `someAsyncFunction(function callback() {})` #1
  3. `foo(42)` #2
  4. `someAsyncFunction(function callback() {})` #2
  5. `callback()` #1 -------> uses `bar`=42
  6. `callback()` #2 -------> uses `bar`=42

Am I correct with this? (does it matter if `bar` is primitive or an object?). If so, what can I do to make sure `callback` uses the correct value of `bar` (ASIDE from passing `bar` all the way down & up the call stack)? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. Each invocation of `foo` creates a new `bar`, so each callback function will have access to a different `bar`.

If you want there to be only one `bar`, declare it outside of `foo` so that each invocation of `foo` shares the same `bar`:

```
var bar;
function foo(arg) {
    bar = arg;
    someAsyncFunction(function callback(err) {
        // do stuff with 'bar'
    });
}
```

Here, `foo` does not declare a new `bar` variable but rather sets the value of `bar` declared in a higher scope.

Comment: 'Each invocation of foo creates a new bar' - this is what was troubling me. Indeed, the example you posted was precisely what I was thinking was happening. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

No, `bar` will still be 20 when the first async callback is executed.  Each call to `foo` gets its own `bar` that's not affected by future calls to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed you're right, but I decided to accept the other answer on the basis that the example he provided allowed me to see the scoping issue easier. Thanks though!